# Automatically calculate order total in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

Is there any way to calculate order total when saving the order detail in backend , without pressing calculate total button .? because some time staff's forgot to press calculate total after editing the item price and save the order . It make trouble to us

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: what do you propose?

Comment: When we call to customer  and they say they need more quanitiy of product then we edit order .Some time my staff forgot to press calculate order total button and they save order . So order total not change in order page and invoice ,even the quantity is changed .So we our requirement is that when they save the order then order total calculate automatically .

Comment: I think this is a core problem... you might be able to get more help from the [developer itself](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues). Just click New Issue button.. and explain as detailed as you can..

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatically-calculate-order-total

Comment: Yes **philip** is right! If you read this tread, Mike Joley (from wooCommerce support team) says: **You would need javascript to trigger 'click' of the calculate button on 'save' inside the order item box**. *(So **philip** you could now auto answer to your question, posting some javascript code and validate it)*